How much must be the current rating of the SMD fuse for the described circuit?
I have a circuit with 12-14 VDC (car power) input, and 5 VDC 750 mA output, and its IC is 'AZ34063UP'.
How much must be the current rating of the SMD fuse at the beginning of input positive line?

Please post the schematics or at least a picture. The presence/absence of electrolyte caps makes a huge difference here.

Your output power is 4 W or so, which equates to about 300 mA at 12 V so you’ll needs a fuse that’s somewhat higher rated than that.  In practice though the fuse is there to protect the wiring, so you should choose a rating that would achieve that. If you’re using (say) 1 mm2 wire then somewhere from 1 to 5 A should do; there’s no need to use the smallest rating that’s just enough to supply the load.

You do not need to fuse this close. The wiring must be protected by the fuse so the fuse blows before the cable. So the fuse could be rated for much more than the typical average DC input current. Why not look at a 1 A fuse?
